# Craft CMS Redactor formatting

Tags: redactor

I am wondering the way to go about modifying the redactor formatting settings either for all the configs or on a per config basis. I want to add custom formatting styles and classes for various text elements. Per the [documentation](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/http://) 
it seems I need to add it with JS (not something I add in a config json file) but i'm not sure where I need to add the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6993/can-i-limit-the-available-styles-from-the-rich-text-field/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use JavaScript to edit the Redactor settings, but the correct answer here is to add the settings with JSON config files. Those should go into your /craft/config/redactor folder.

Take look at the [Redactor Styles](https://github.com/aelvan/RedactorStyles-Craft/) plugin though – it will add a couple of textareas to your CP for adding custom Redactor JSON and/or CSS, which should make this a bit easier.

Comment: Also, see this related thread: <http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/238/how-do-i-add-custom-styles-plugins-to-the-rich-text-editor-in-craft>